# ANTLR parse assignments

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr3

I want to parse some assignments, where I only care about the assignment as a whole. Not about whats inside the assignment. An assignment is indiciated by `':='`. (EDIT: Before and after the assignments  other things may come)

Some examples:

```
a := TRUE & FALSE;
c := a ? 3 : 5;
b := case 
          a : 1;
          !a : 0;
        esac;
```

Currently I make a difference between assignments containing a 'case' and other assignments. For simple assignments I tried something like `~('case' | 'esac' | ';')` but then antlr complained about unmatched tokens (like `'='`).

```
assignment : 
   NAME ':='! expression ;

expression : 
    ( simple_expression | case_expression) ;


simple_expression : 
    ((OPERATOR | NAME) & ~('case' | 'esac'))+  ';'! ;

case_expression : 
    'case' .+ 'esac' ';'! ;
```

I tried replacing with the following, because the eclipse-interpreter did not seem to like the `((OPERATOR | NAME) & ~('case' | 'esac'))+  ';'! ;` because of the `'and'`.

```
   (~(OPERATOR | ~NAME | ('case' | 'esac')) |
    ~(~OPERATOR | NAME | ('case' | 'esac')) |
    ~(~OPERATOR | ~NAME | ('case' | 'esac')))  ';'!
```

But this does not work. I get

> "error(139): /AntlrTutorial/src/foo/NusmvInput.g:78:5: set complement is empty |---> ~(~OPERATOR | ~NAME | ('case' | 'esac')))  EOC! ;"

How can I parse it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things going wrong here:

- you're using `&` in your grammar while it should be with quotes around it: `'&'`
- unless you know exactly what you're doing, don't use `~` and `.` (especially not `.+` !) inside parser rules: use them in lexer rules only;
- create lexer rules instead of defining `'case'` and `'esac'` in your parser rules (it's safe to use literal tokens in your parser rules if no other lexer rule can potentially match is, but `'case'` and `'esac'` *look* a lot like `NAME` *and* they could end up in your AST in which case it's better to explicitly define them yourself in the lexer)

Here's a quick demo:

```
grammar T;

options {
  output=AST;
}

tokens {
  ROOT;
  CASES;
  CASE;
}

parse
 : (assignment SCOL)* EOF -> ^(ROOT assignment*)
 ;

assignment 
 : NAME ASSIGN^ expression 
 ;

expression
 : ternary_expression
 ;

ternary_expression
 : or_expression (QMARK^ ternary_expression COL! ternary_expression)?
 ;

or_expression
 : unary_expression ((AND | OR)^ unary_expression)*
 ;

unary_expression
 : NOT^ atom
 | atom
 ;

atom
 : TRUE
 | FALSE
 | NUMBER
 | NAME
 | CASE single_case+ ESAC -> ^(CASES single_case+)
 | '(' expression ')'     -> expression
 ;

single_case
 : expression COL expression SCOL -> ^(CASE expression expression)
 ;

TRUE   : 'TRUE';
FALSE  : 'FALSE';
CASE   : 'case';
ESAC   : 'esac';
ASSIGN : ':='; 
AND    : '&';
OR     : '|';
NOT    : '!';
QMARK  : '?';
COL    : ':';
SCOL   : ';';
NAME   : ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')+;
NUMBER : ('0'..'9')+;
SPACE  : (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n')+ {skip();};
```

which will parse your input:

```
a := TRUE & FALSE;
c := a ? 3 : 5;
b := case 
          a : 1;
          !a : 0;
        esac;
```

as follows:

[image]

Comment: I had not completely understood the mechanics of lexer and parser, so thats what I should work on ^^. Your solution  certainly has given me some insights, thanks.